# generate xml files based on my c# classes

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-serialization

i have xml file that i need to update each and every time as per new client requirement.
most of the time xml is not proper because of manual updation of xml file.
I am thinking to write a program (web/windows) where proper validation is provided.
and based on the input from ui I will going to create xml file.
below is my sample xml file.

```
<community>
  <author>xxx xxx</author>
  <communityid>000</communityid>
  <name>name of the community</name>

<addresses>
        <registeredaddress>
          <addressline1>xxx</addressline1>
          <addressline2>xxx</addressline2>
          <addressline3>xxx</addressline3>
          <city>xxx</city>
          <county>xx</county>
          <postcode>0000-000</postcode>
          <country>xxx</country>
        </registeredaddress>
        <tradingaddress>
          <addressline1>xxx</addressline1>
          <addressline2>xxx</addressline2>
          <addressline3>xxx</addressline3>
          <city>xxx</city>
          <county>xx</county>
          <postcode>0000-000</postcode>
          <country>xxx</country>
        </tradingaddress>
      </addresses>


<community>
```

can any one help me what will be the best approach for this?

Comment: What kind of validation are you talking about?

Comment: like for post code field regular expression

Comment: @Prashant is it important for xml tags to be lowercase?

Comment: yes. actually this xml is import by some other legacy tool for further processing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create following classes to hold your data and validate it:

```
public class Community
{
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public int CommunityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(RegisteredAddress))]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(TradingAddress))]
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    private string _postCode;

    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public string PostCode
    {
        get { return _postCode; }
        set {
            // validate post code e.g. with RegEx
            _postCode = value; 
        }
    }
}

public class RegisteredAddress : Address { }
public class TradingAddress : Address { }
```

And serialize that instance of community class to xml:

```
Community community = new Community {
    Author = "xxx xxx",
    CommunityId = 0,
    Name = "name of community",
    Addresses = new List<Address> {
        new RegisteredAddress {
            AddressLine1 = "xxx",
            AddressLine2 = "xxx",
            AddressLine3 = "xxx",
            City = "xx",
            Country = "xxxx",
            PostCode = "0000-00"
        },
        new TradingAddress {
            AddressLine1 = "zz",
            AddressLine2 = "xxx"
        }
    }
};

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Community));
serializer.Serialize(File.Create("file.xml"), community);
```

I think a little googling will help you to understand how to deserialize community object back from file.

Comment: xml tags in xml are same as in cs files. how can i make to smaller case as in my original xml file.

Comment: @Prashant use `XmlElement` attributes. Like this `[XmlElement("name")] public string Name { get; set; }` also you will need `XmlRoot` attribute for community class.

Comment: Can you specify the namespace of `XmlSerializer`, would've spared the google search.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old topic, but I wanted to give my own share.
The xml you provided above is not valid, so I am using xml below as an example.

1. First, structure your xml how you want it to look like. Let's say it is going to look like this:

   ```
   <note>
         <to>Tove</to>
         <from>Jani</from>
         <heading>Reminder</heading>
         <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
   </note>
   ```
2. Copy your xml code
3. Go to Visual Studio
4. Create a class file and clear the code in it
5. Then on the menu, click `Edit\Paste Special\Paste Xml as Classes`

Visual studio will generate the entire class.

```
Core/Standard 2.0.
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class note
{

    private string toField;

    private string fromField;

    private string headingField;

    private string bodyField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string to
    {
        get
        {
            return this.toField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.toField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string from
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fromField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.fromField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string heading
    {
        get
        {
            return this.headingField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.headingField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string body
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bodyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bodyField = value;
        }
    }
}
```