# Is there a way to save a list of objects in dataset in c#

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I want to save a list of dates in an xml, I want to use dataset to achieve the task, I do the same to a database using Entity Framework. This allows me to access the dates using `event.eventDates.start`
but in the dataset I cannot achieve it.

```
   public class Event
    {
        [Key]
        public string id { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Date> eventDates { get; set; }
    }
```

Date class

```
   public class Date
    {
        public DateTime start { get; set; }
        public DateTime end { get; set; }
    }
```

When using entity framework I can access the eventDates Object using `event.eventDates.start`
I mapped the data from the sql database in the dataset builder the relations look like this

[image]

I want the xml file to be in this format

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<db xmlns="http://tempuri.org/LocalDB.xsd">
  <Event>
    <id>ID</id>
    <eventdates>
      <date>
         <startdate></startdate>
         <enddate></enddate>
      <date>  
      <date>
         <startdate></startdate>
         <enddate></enddate>
      <date>  
    </eventdates>
  </Event>
</db>
```

Is there any way to achieve that using datasets?
I'm new to C# any help would be appreciated

Comment: If yyour objects are serializable you can save the string in the db.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953311/generate-xml-files-based-on-my-c-sharp-classes

Answer (score 0):

This code works, based on [generate xml files based on my c# classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953311/generate-xml-files-based-on-my-c-sharp-classes). I would rename your classes to something else than "Event" and "Date". These names are too generic and are usually protected by the system. ICollection is not serializable. Read [XML serialization of interface property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333864/xml-serialization-of-interface-property). You can use DTO or you can change the collection type (i.e. with List<>) and with XML serialization attributes avoid circular references and/or disable lazy load (i.e. use eagerly load using Include method) or the risk is that you serialize the whole database.

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace EFToXml
{
    public class MyEvent
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public virtual List<MyDate> EventDates { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyDate
    {
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myDate1 = new MyDate
            {
                Start = DateTime.Now,
                End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
            };
            var eventDates = new List<MyDate> { myDate1 };
            var myEvent = new MyEvent
            {
                Id = "1",
                EventDates = eventDates
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyEvent));
            serializer.Serialize(File.Create(@"C:\Users\<UserName>\Source\Repos\myEvents.xml"), myEvent);

        }
    }
}
```

myEvents.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MyEvent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Id>1</Id>
  <EventDates>
    <MyDate>
      <Start>2019-11-24T21:52:04.5032671+01:00</Start>
      <End>2019-11-25T21:52:04.5194026+01:00</End>
    </MyDate>
  </EventDates>
</MyEvent>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you just want to reproduce EntityFramework's behavior using DataSets.
You can achieve exactly same thing simply creating DataSet (using integrated VisualStudio designer) with proper tables, fields and relations:

[image: Dataset example]

later on you can access your data using code like this:

```
var ds = new DataSet1();
var ue = ds.UserEvents.FirstOrDefault();
var ued = ue.GetChildRows("FK_UserEvents_EventDates")
          .Cast<DataSet1.EventDatesRow>();

var date = ued.FirstOrDefault().Date;
```

Next thing to do is serialization - it's quite easy:
[Serialization example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/4d56e1/serializing-a-dataset-object-as-xml/)